# How to remove leading zeroes in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

```
           05 nStateNumOut   PIC 99.
           05 filler         PIC XX                VALUE SPACES.
           05 xOutputName    PIC X(20).
           05 filler         PIC XX                VALUE SPACES.
           05 neOutputPop    PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ9(8).
           05 filler         PIC XX                VALUE SPACES.
           05 neOutputArea   PIC ZZZ,ZZZ9(6).
           05 neOutputDen    PIC ZZZ,ZZZ9,999.99.
           05 neTotalPopOut  PIC ZZZ,ZZZ9(10).
```

I need to get rid of leading zeros and place commas where needed. This what I get for as my end result.

```
 Alabama               04447100  050750  00087
00  Alaska                00626932  570374  00001
00  Arizona               05130632  113642  00045
```

Comment: I don't see how those results have anything to do with the input, and have no commas at all.

Comment: the last bit is the output. the First part is what i Am suppose to edit in order to add commas and get rid of the leading zeros

Comment: The parts that are missing:

Variable definitions for the "origin" and the actual `MOVE` that place those in the ne-variables.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I recall from 45 years ago. PIC ZZZ ,ZZZ9(6) is a 12-digit number that has 6 zero-suppressed digits and 6 non-zero-suppressed digits, as well as a single curiously-placed comma separator.

Don't write 9(6) if you don't want leading zeroes.  Using Z(6).  Or maybe Z(5)9.

Did you really need 12 digits for 'area' with a comma every 3 digits?  If so, that would be PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.

---

Example: executed at https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-cobol-online/

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. ZERO.
DATA DIVISION.
    WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        77 X PIC Z(8)9.
        77 Y PIC 9(9).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
    MOVE 1234 TO X.
    MOVE 1234 TO Y.
    DISPLAY 'X=', X, ' Y=', Y.
STOP RUN.
```

Displays

```
X=     1234 Y=000001234
```

Comment: okay I tried the z(6) method and it still has leading zeros

Comment: Works for me, see edit.

Comment: How do the data get into those fields?  Is the partial structure you show part of a record definition?   Do the data already exist with leading zeroes in a data file?  Hypothesis: if you wrote the record with leading zeroes, reading it in again with a different PIC will not update individual fields to reflect the new PIC.  But since we have no code to look at, it's hard to say.  Can you post a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Your declarations define too large fields. e.g.

```
05 neOutputPop    PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ9(8).
```

This is equivalent to:

```
05 neOutputPop    PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZZ99999999.
```

Now only numbers larger than 99999999 will have any digits in the positions where you want zero suppression. In your sample data, the population numbers are 8 digit numbers, so no non-zero digit in the "Z" places.

Your declarations already do have the leading zero suppression, and in fact it does work, because you don't see zeros in the "Z" positions. Right?

What you need is

```
05 neOutputPop    PIC ZZZ,ZZZ,ZZ9.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how many digits you want to display at most, so I post a general solution:

```
    05  9digits         pic zzz,zzz,zz9.
```

This will show

```
          1
         12
        123
      1,234
     12,345
    123,456
  1,234,567
 12,345,678
123,456,789
```